# Updating webclient response from database

Tags: sql, kotlin, sql-update, webclient, flatmap

I have situation where I can't update column at database.
The problem is that only method `setIsPurchased` is executed and the flag `is_purchase` at SQL table changed to true, but the next line with `setPurchasedDate` which has to set current time is not executed. The response from database is `Mono<Void>` type.

```
fun purchase(uuid: UUID, request: PurchaseInternalRequest) =
        extraProductTransactionService.findTransactionByUuid(uuid)
            .doOnNext { it.validateNotPurchased() }
            .flatMap { purchaseViaSupplier(it, request) }
            .flatMap { extraProductTransactionService.setIsPurchased(uuid) }
            .flatMap { extraProductTransactionService.setPurchasedDate(uuid) }
            .onErrorMap(Exception::class.java) { Exception(it.status) }
            .then()
```

Queries for those two method are simple and looks like:

For `setIsPurchased`:

`update extra_product_transactions SET is_purchased = 1 where uuid = :uuid`

For `setPurchasedDate`:

`update extra_product_transactions SET purchased_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where uuid = :uuid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Mono<Void>` by essence never emits an element `onNext()`. Having said that, `.flatMap { extraProductTransactionService.setPurchasedDate(uuid) }` is never invoked.

I assume you are not interested in the return values of the `set` methods so you can do something like:

```kotlin
fun purchase(uuid: UUID, request: PurchaseInternalRequest) =
    extraProductTransactionService.findTransactionByUuid(uuid)
        .doOnNext { it.validateNotPurchased() }
        .flatMap { purchaseViaSupplier(it, request) }
        .flatMap { 
          extraProductTransactionService.setIsPurchased(uuid).subscribe()
          extraProductTransactionService.setPurchasedDate(uuid)
        }
        .onErrorMap(Exception::class.java) { Exception(it.status) }
        .then()
```

Comment: Thank you for your approach, I decied to change it to one query. I mean ```setIsPurchasedAndPurchasedAt```. For your information, I tried change return type to something else than ```Mono<void>``` (Mono<Boolean>) the problem do not disappear

Comment: I am confused. Is your problem fixed now?

Comment: Yes, now my code looks like 
```fun purchase(uuid: UUID, request: PurchaseInternalRequest) =

        extraProductTransactionService.findTransactionByUuid(uuid)

            .doOnNext { it.validateNotPurchased() }

            .flatMap { purchaseViaSupplier(it, request) }

            .flatMap { extraProductTransactionService.setIsPurchasedAndPurchasedAt(uuid) }
            .onErrorMap(Exception::class.java) { Exception(it.status) }
            .then()```
where ```setIsPurchasedAndPurchasedAt``` is query to update both values. Best regards

Comment: PS Sorry for style of message but here i can't edit it

Comment: Great! If my answer helped you upvote it or even accept is as the answer to your question so that others may benefit from it and understand easily what a solution could look like. Thanks!